# Laravel put :notify to the end of redis keys

Tags: php, laravel, redis, predis

recently I migrate from laravel 5.7 to 8 and some queues that dispatch from laravel has add to end of its key name ":notify"... somebody know why and how avoid this?.. i'm using predis as client.

Comment: there are few states > :notify, :reserved, :delayed. You can see RedisQueue.php and LuaScripts.php file at the queue src (at the vendor).

Comment: thanks to answer @Svetoslav is there ... i verified in Laravel 5.7 only exist :reserved, :delayed .. starting laravel 5.8 they add :notify